# Account IDs and Usage

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

This is a pretty basic question, but across the various account types is there a uniqueness between the various types in terms of the AcctID's? So if a savings had AcctID=123456, would there ever be a situation with a checking deposit account with the same AcctID, just different AcctType? We have a client mentioning their call center and digital banking only uses the AcctID (they call it account number) and we are wondering how or if the AcctType is handled when customers are referencing their account online or via a bank call center. This is specific to Silverlake, by the way,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per JHA VIP they are not unique across account types.